# Change position of responsive side menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have little side menu for the phones and tablet that visit my site. The problem is that the hamburguer icon that opens the menu is on the right side of the top bar, but the menu opens from the left side. I want to make the menu open from the right side aswell. What do I have to change?

This is my code (Taken from w3schools):

```
    <nav class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-black w3-card w3-animate-left w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large" style="display:none" id="mySidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3-padding-16">Close ×</a>
  <a href="Inicio.html" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">INICIO</a>
  <a href="Stock.html" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">NUESTROS COCHES</a>
  <a href="Contacto.html" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">CONTACTO</a>
</nav>
```

And this is the JS script:

```
var mySidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");

function w3_open() {
    if (mySidebar.style.display === 'block') {
        mySidebar.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        mySidebar.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

// Close the sidebar with the close button
function w3_close() {
    mySidebar.style.display = "none";
}
```

The CSS is the W3 one you can find it in this link:https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css

Comment: Please provide a complete example in your question. The code you provided does not have the button element used to open the sidebar. This is a good candidate for a snippet (when entering your question look for the code snippet button or press Ctrl+M to create a snippet) which lets us run your code and see what's wrong very easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the w3 sidebar example, they show how to move it to the right in the bottom  of the page:

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_sidebar.asp

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed pretty easily. You just need to switch the `w3-animate-left` to `w3-animate-right`. This will use the correct animation from to move out from the right side of the screen.

You also need to make the sidebar stay at the right side of the screen after the animation is complete. To do this, just add `right: 0` to `.w3-sidebar`.

```
.w3-sidebar {
    right: 0;
}
```

It also helps to read [the rest of the post](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_sidebar.asp) (see the section title "Right-sided Side Navigation"). ;)

```js
var mySidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");

function w3_open() {
  if (mySidebar.style.display === 'block') {
    mySidebar.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    mySidebar.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

// Close the sidebar with the close button
function w3_close() {
  mySidebar.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.w3-sidebar {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" type="text/css">

<nav class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-black w3-card w3-animate-right w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large" id="mySidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3-padding-16">Close ×</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">INICIO</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">NUESTROS COCHES</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">CONTACTO</a>
</nav>

<button onclick="w3_open()">Open<button>
```